# Socket error #103 Software caused connection abort. DELPHI10.4

Tags: delphi, connection, firemonkey

I've made a customer app and it works all fine but now I have a few emails that get this error.
[image]

This error pops up when they send a service request. in the code, they write the request in the database and send a confirmation mail to them. This works with the SMTP component. There about 600 users that have the app. I don't know if that causes the problem.

I have a few questions.

- how does this error arise?
- What is the best solution to fix this problem?

I use the next connection components.
-FDconnection(Make the connection from the app to the server)
-DSTCPServerTransport (To make the connection from the server to the app and database).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: At first glance, I would suspect a *security* product that looks for internet access. If it did not happen before, maybe an update of that security product. Ask the customer if they use/installed/updated. Suggest to disable temporarily that product.

Comment: Network knowledge 101: connections can be cut. From any end.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for your help i will ask it again and change it when they remove it

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I edited my first question and added that other questions didn't had the result